# Bind Angular with dynamic data from database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am pretty new to Angularjs and I would like to achieve an editable table similar to this jsfiddel `http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/` (retrieved from the official angular doc) however instead of hardcoded data, how can I fill the table with a List of data retrieved from the database in MVC or a ViewBag?

for example instead of this MVC table below I would like to achieve to achieve the same thing but instead using Angular to make the table editable.

```
@if (ViewBag.Session != null)
{
<table class="table table-hover">
     <tr>
        <th>
            ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Surname
        </th>
        <th>
            House
        </th>
        <th>
            Address
        </th>
        <th>
            Locality
        </th>
        <th>
            Contact
        </th>
        <th>
            Contact 2
        </th>
        <th>
            Contact 3
        </th>
        <th>
            Reply
        </th>
        <th>
            Edit
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Session)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.ID
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Surname
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.House
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Address
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Locality
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Contact1
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Contact2
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Contact3
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Reply
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Additionally, when a row is changed and saved, how can the data be sent back to the backed to be save in the database?

Comment: AngularJS has a very different approach that ASP.NET MVC. Try learn about angular first https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good idea for you to read a jumpstart tutorial, training, or book.

Here you have a link to get started using web api in the server side plus angularjs on the client, it just load a list of items from the server.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ja2xDrtylBw